# MySQL Optimize Select with Coalesce

Tags: mysql, select, optimization

Advise how to optimize this query? I made indexes, but from this the processing time does not change. The database has 4 million rows :(

```
SELECT id as ID,
COALESCE(name,name2,name2) AS USERNAME,
CONCAT_WS(' ',ip, ip2, ip3) AS 'IP',
CONCAT_WS('_',
CASE when cluster LIKE '%domain1%' then 'DOM1' END,
CASE when cluster1 LIKE '%domain2%' then 'DOM2' END,
CASE when cluster2 LIKE '%domain3%' then 'DOM3' END) AS CLUSTER,
COALESCE(data,data2,data3) AS Data
FROM table
WHERE data = '2020-01-02' or data3 = '2020-01-02' or data3 = '2020-01-02'
```

Comment: There is only one point to optimize - WHERE with OR. If the selectivity of the condition is high then you may create separate indices by `dateX` fields and use 3 separate subqueries combined with UNION DISTINCT.

Comment: Could you please update your questions and  put index and execution plan in it?

Comment: The first step would be to  normalise your schema. Any time you find yourself with enumerated column names, you have to consider whether your schema design is optimal

Comment: And statements like `or data3 = '2020-01-02' or data3 = '2020-01-02'` are symptomatic of a lack of care and attention